# How to forward tokens without paying a gas

Tags: contract-development, wallets, address.transfer

I'm working on a project and I need to know if this statement is possible:

- I have 10 registered users. Each user has an erc20 wallet. It is possible that when user A, C, E, or whoever deposit their token to their specific address the funds goes to the main wallet instead of the alias one? we could avoid the gas expenses if we create an alias that works as a wallet.

We are going to receive our own token, which has no value at the moment, so we can't use it to pay comission

I have been reading a lot, but can't find out a solution

Answer (score 3):

There are no "wallet aliases" in Ethereum. Sounds like you came up with this term yourself.

It is not possible to avoid paying gas and somebody needs to pay for it. Ethereum network is public infrastructure and its security is supported by the transaction fees. There are some other blockchains, like EOS, which offer limited free tier transactions that are not guaranteed.

Usually the gas cost is pushed to the user, so you do not need to pay for it, but however deposits the token must have ETH to cover the gas fee. You can create a payment forwarder smart contract that pushes the token all the way main wallet and the users will be ones paying the gas fees.

You can, in theory, use layer 2 network like LoopRing or StarkDex to do have very minimal fees or no fees. However, this is very complicated solution and it does not sound like it is in a reach of your project yet.

When your token has a value you can recommend users to use a wallet that supports Gas Station Network and then pay the fees through a fee market with your own token.

https://www.opengsn.org/

Comment: Hello, regarding _You can create a payment forwarder smart contract that pushes the token all the way main wallet and the users will be ones paying the gas fees._ - can you please expand on this a bit? since I've seen on other places the exchange pays for fees? Because, how can the user know how much fee will he pay if he sends from metamask?